# PHP How to detect value location in array?

Tags: php, attributes, html-rendering

I am writing a function to render styles and scripts files along with detecting their version and ran into a problem. Because I would like to simply list the values ​​of the attributes in the array. But I don't know how to make it automatically match the values ​​to the variables in the function in no matter what order they are put into the array

**Render Code**

```
renderScripts([[
'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js',
'async','defer'
],[
'nonce','https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdB0VaoC-NxaBE'
],[
'/js/app.js','sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS'
]]);
```

**Render Function**

```
if(!function_exists('renderScripts')){
    function renderScripts($files){
        foreach($files as $file){
            var_dump($file);
            return ('<script '.(isset($file['async'])) ? 'async ' : ''.(isset($file['defer'])) ? 'defer ' : ''.(isset($file['nomodule'])) ? 'nomodule ' : ''.(isset($file['nonce'])) ? 'nonce ' : ''.(isset($file['type'])) ? 'type="'.$file['type'].'" ' : 'type="text/javascript" '.'src="'.autoVersion($file[0]).'"'.(isset($file['integrity'])) ? 'integrity="'.$file['integrity'].'" ' : ''.(isset($file['crossorigin'])) ? 'crossorigin="'.$file['crossorigin'].'" ' : ''.(isset($file['referrerpolicy'])) ? 'referrerpolicy="'.$file['referrerpolicy'].'" ' : ''.'></script>');
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to do it with a shortened version of the table, but nw how to do it to insert data correctly regardless of the order of attributes. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: I _think_ you just need to perform pattern/string matching. You have some literals such as `async` and `defer` that you can check for with using `in_array()`. If it starts with `sha256/284/512` then you have an SRI. Repeat, unsetting each time when done and what is left is probably the URL, although you might also need to deal with relative/absolute

Comment: @ChrisHaas And you will correct this code for me because I don't know how to check the type, hash and link https://hastebin.com/aqokeyelak.rb

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are saying that you are trying limit the amount of code at the call site. This isn't by itself a bad thing, but you are making a tradeoff when it comes to complexity and explicitness.

Take `234892398`. That is 100% valid as both a `nonce` and a `src`. Also, `application/javascript` is also 100% valid for `type` and `src`. You and I know what these are for, but you'll have to tell the computer and just make assumptions. If your code is controlled, this might not be a problem, but it is something you should be aware of.

Second, have a [copy of a specification handy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) because you will need to handle all possible things, or ignore the ones that you don't support.

Third, I'm ignoring `nonce` as a value because that is a literal, not a "number used once" so it isn't a nonce and therefor not secure. If you want that, I'll leave that up to you.

Fourth, I'm separating attribute searching from creating the HTML. You don't have to do this, but it is so much easier to debug.

Fifth, because you wanted a terse call-site, the function is much more verbose. You could find a way to shorten it, and if you are running PHP 8+ I'd recommend [`match`](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-match-or-switch), but once again, verbose code is usually easier to debug.

Sixth, I'm not doing any escaping. Please don't trust user input and make sure that you sanitize things appropriately.

With all of that said, here's the function:

```php
function renderScripts($files)
{
    $buf = '';
    foreach ($files as $arbitraryCollectionOfThingsRelatedToScriptTags) {
        $attributes = [];

        foreach ($arbitraryCollectionOfThingsRelatedToScriptTags as $value) {
            // No idea what to do with this. If someone is using the literal 'nonce' as a nonce, I'd recommend skipping it
            if ('nonce' === $value) {
                continue;
            }
            if (in_array($value, ['nomodule', 'async', 'defer'], true)) {
                $attributes[$value] = null;
                continue;
            }

            if (in_array($value, ['no-referrer', 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', 'origin', 'origin-when-cross-origin', 'same-origin', 'strict-origin', 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'unsafe-url'], true)) {
                $attributes['referrerpolicy'] = $value;
                continue;
            }

            if (preg_match('/^sha(256|384|512)/', $value)) {
                $attributes['integrity'] = $value;
                continue;
            }

            if (preg_match('/^(text|application)\/[a-zA-Z]+/', $value)) {
                $attributes['type'] = $value;
                continue;
            }

            $attributes['src'] = $value;
        }

        $buf .= '<script';
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
            if (null === $value) {
                $buf .= " ${key}";
            } else {
                $buf .= " ${key}=\"${value}\"";
            }
        }
        $buf .= '></script>';
    }
    return $buf;

}
```

When run with this dataset:

```php
$files = [[
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js',
    'async', 'defer'
], [
    'nonce', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdB0VaoC-NxaBE'
], [
    '/js/app.js', 'sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS'
]];


echo renderScripts($files);
```

You get:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" async defer></script><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdB0VaoC-NxaBE"></script><script src="/js/app.js" integrity="sha384-0m
SbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"></script>
```

Comment: Before you sent me this function, I made 90% similar but shorter and is this mine also good or is it better to use yours? https://hastebin.com/onotacesum.php

Comment: Code that works is what matters. I would add some tests to make sure that what you put in is what comes out. I still don't know what you are trying to do with `nonce`. I know what a nonce is but how you are using it is not correct. Your code also appears to assume that `true` or `false` can be used for `nomodule` which is not obvious to me, but as long as it works for you. I still agree with the other answer where using named keys is so much cleaner and less error prone.

Comment: And how would I like to make these 2 ways work, how do I do it? Because in total, I would like to be able to make a longer version and make it longer by giving the hardness for the appropriate names of the attributes

Comment: I'm not really sure what your comment/question is about. It might be easier to create a new question because it seems that this is diverging from what your original one was about. I think, but I could be wrong, that we have you convinced that just using an array  with values only as you started with is error prone, and you'd like to find some middle ground. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you're going to pass the array to `renderScripts` function manually or by fetching it from somewhere, but instead of passing it as an indexed array, it will be better to pass named array like this

```php
renderScripts([
    [
        'src' => 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js',
        'async' => null,
        'defer' => null
    ],
    [
        'nonce' => null,
        'src' => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LdB0VaoC-NxaBE'
    ],
    [
        'src' => '/js/app.js',
        'integrity' => 'sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS'
    ]
])
```

And then you can modify your function accordingly like this

```php
if (! function_exists('renderScripts')){
    function renderScripts($files) {
        $scripts = [];
        foreach($files as $file){
            $script = "<script";

            foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
                $script .= " {$key}";

                if (! is_null($value)) {
                    $script .= "=\"{$value}\"";
                }
            }

            if (! in_array('type', array_keys($file))) {
                $script .= " type=\"text/javascript\"";
            }

            $script .= "></script>";

            $scripts[] = $script;
        }

        return $scripts;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, but I would like to do it with an index table to limit the amount of code and not to clutter the functions of creating tags. At first I wanted to make a function similar to wordpress, but I have scripts with different values, so I decided to do a function that will contain information and script values ​​in the indexed array.

Comment: Thanks to the advice of the person above, I have already done an almost ready function, but I have to check if the index in the array is a hash and save it once with a link and type, but I don't know how to do it. I try to do regEx which will detect and get the type but only catch "text / j" or "application / j" and not the full value